# C++ pointer declaration to access arrays of pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I need help with a pointer declaration, I have several classes with arrays of pointers eg.

```
const char* const clsMainWin::mcpszXMLattrRoot[] = {"bottom","left","right","top",NULL};
const char* const clsMainWin::mcpszXMLattrA[] = {"x","y","z",NULL};
```

What I want to do is define a pointer which groups the above arrays of pointers allowing me to select one of the about with a single index, eg:

```
const char* const allOptions[] = {mcpszXMLattrRoot, mcpszXMLattrA};
```

Where:

```
allOptions[0][...] would be used to access mcpszXMLattrRoot and its contents:
allOptions[1][...] would be used to access mcpszXMLattrA and its contents
```

However so far I'm struggling to get the declaration of allOptions correct.

Comment: You can't really do that, because `mcpszXMLattrRoot` and `mcpszXMLattrA` are different types, which means you can't collect them into the same array. The type of `mcpszXMLattrRoot` is `const char * const [5]`, while the type of `mcpszXMLattrA` is `const char * const [4]`. The number of elements in the arrays are part of the type, and an array can only contain elements of the same type.

Comment: this is a C++ question, not a C question.  please remove the `c` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the pointer of `mcpszXMLattrRoot` and `mcpszXMLattrA` (i.e. `const char * const *`.

```
const char* const * allOptions[] = {mcpszXMLattrRoot, mcpszXMLattrA};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static const char* const a[] = {"a1", "a2", "a3"};
static const char* const b[] = {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"};
static const char* const* const z[] = {a, b};
```

The type of `z` has an additional `*` because it is an array of pointers to arrays of pointers of char.

You need `const` before the latter `*` because `a` and `b` are const. Without constantness it would be:

```
static const char* a[] = {"a1", "a2", "a3"};
static const char* b[] = {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"};
static const char** z[] = {a, b};
```

You can initialize it in-class with `constexpr`

```
class Foo {
    static constexpr const char* const a[] = {"a1", "a2", "a3"};
    static constexpr const char* const b[] = {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"};
    static constexpr const char* const* z[] = {a, b};
};
```

Or out-class:

```
class Foo {
    static const char* const a[];
    static const char* const b[];
    static const char* const* z[];
};

const char* const Foo::a[] = {"a1", "a2", "a3"};
const char* const Foo::b[]= {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"};
const char* const* Foo::z[] = {a, b};
```

Comment: Trying this now:  const char* const * clsMainWin::mcppAttributes[]

Comment: This answer won't allow accessing with a single index.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved as:

```
class clsMainWin{
    static const char* const mcpszXMLattrRoot[5];
    static const char* const mcpszXMLattrA[4];
    static const char* const *allOptions[2];

    // And other things....

};

const char* const clsMainWin::mcpszXMLattrRoot[] = {"bottom","left","right","top",NULL};
const char* const clsMainWin::mcpszXMLattrA[] = {"x","y","z",NULL};
const char*const * clsMainWin::allOptions[2] = {mcpszXMLattrRoot, mcpszXMLattrA};
```